# Concat or Join list of "names" in Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, wcf

Using WCF RIA I have a query that returns a Query of names

```
public class WitnessInfo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid WCFId { get; set; }
    public string witnessName { get; set; }
    public string AllNames {get; set;}

}
```

Here's my Linq Query

```
[Query]
    public IQueryable<WitnessInfo> getWitnessInfo(int? id)
    {
        IQueryable<WitnessInfo> witnessQuery = from witness in this.Context.witness
                                               where witness.DAFile.Id == id
                                               select new WitnessInfo
                                               {
                                                   WCFId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                                   witnessName = witness.Person.FirstName,

                                               };
        return witnessQuery;

    }
```

I want to take all the names and return them in a single string i.e "John, James, Tim, Jones". Tried taking AllNames and looping through but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: **Where** are all these names located? In `AllNames`?

Comment: You can use the `Aggregate` LINQ method, or you can do `string.Join(", ", yourQuery.Select(i => i.WitnessName).ToArray())`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel yea I want to add all the names in AllNames

Comment: @Luaan Using `Aggregate` would result in many string concatenations, which is a highly inefficient algorithm; it'd be doing a lot of wasted work.

Comment: @Servy You can use StringBuilder in Aggregate. But you're right, I should have said that that's a good idea :)

Comment: @Luaan But why would you bother, when there's `string.Join` to do it not only more easily, but more efficiently?

Comment: @Servy: Because `string.Join` requires an `string[]`, while `Aggregate` does not. You avoid allocating all the strings in an array first.

Comment: @Luaan That's not true as of .NET 4.0.  `Join` accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @Servy: Oh, cool, I didn't know that. I still have to work on the ASP.NET 2.0 stack, so I'm stuck with .NET 3.5. In that case, on 4.0+ your points are entirely valid and your approach is better. Also, it seems we might all be missing the point - neither of these approaches can be used in an IQueryable on a DB server - they need you to get all the data first, which might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Luaan The DB can't do this any more effectively than the application can; the DB is sending exactly the same data; it's just formatted slightly differently.  There's no real *reason* to try to do this on the DB end.

Comment: @Servy: Ah, sorry. I meant a scenario where he'd want to use the return of this method (which is still an IQueryable) inside of another database query - both `string.Join` and `Aggregate` are probably going to fail in that case.

Comment: @Luaan In that case one merely needs to not turn the collection of names into a single string until you're done; do all of the other DB operations while propogating a collection of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First grab all of the information that you need in a single query, then use `String.Join` to map the collection of names to a single string:

```
var firstQuery = from witness in Context.witness
    where witness.DAFile.Id == id
    select new
    {
        WCFId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        witnessName = witness.Person.FirstName,
        Names = Context.witness.Select(w => w.FirstName),
    })
    .AsEnumerable(); //do the rest in linq to objects

var finalQuery = from witness in firstQuery
    //do the string manipulation just once
    let allNames = string.Join(", ", witness.Names)
    select new WitnessInfo
    {
        WCFId = witness.WCFId,
        witnessName = witness.witnessName,
        AllNames = allNames,
    });
```

Comment: `Names = Context.witness.Select(w => w.FirstName)` isn't it inner heavy query?

Comment: @YairNevet If it were linq to objects, yes, and it would be terrible, but it's not, the whole thing just gets compiled into an expression, which is sent to the DB as SQL, and an inner query in SQL, when it doesn't depend on captured identifiers from the outer query, won't be executed for each item.  It will be executed once and it's results re-used for each item in the query.

Answer (score 1):

By having the `AllNames` property in the `WitnessInfo` class, it is seems like you want each `WitnessInfo` object to contain the all of the squence names *again and again* repeatedly, and if this is your case then do it like that:

```
var names = (from witness in this.Context.witness
                select witness.Person.FirstName).ToArray();

var allNames = string.Join(", ", names);

IQueryable<WitnessInfo> witnessQuery = from witness in this.Context.witness
                                       where witness.DAFile.Id == id
                                       select new WitnessInfo
                                       {
                                           WCFId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                           witnessName = witness.Person.FirstName,
                                           AllNames = allNames
                                       };
```

Comment: Note that this is performing two round trips to the database.

Comment: @Servy Not anymore, I use `ToArray()`

Comment: @YairNevet You most certainly *are* making two round trips.  You're making two queries; the first query, names, and the second query, `witnessQuery`.

Comment: @Servy Okay, any alternative?

Comment: @YairNevet Sure; get all of the information in one single query, as seen in my answer.

Comment: @Servy, I saw it, nice!

Comment: @YairNevet yea sorry he's right, more efficient answer is his.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate like this:

```
string.Join(", ", getWithnessInfo(666).Select(wq => wq.witnessName))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Context.witness.Select(a => a.Person.Firstname).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```

Comment: Performing an unknown number of string concatenations like this is highly inefficient and results in a lot of wasted effort.